# Why is the aws cli not found on amazonlinux2 ami?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-linux-2

The AmazonLinux2 AMI I am using for my Docker hosts does not appear to have the AWS CLI installed. The log has an error from the user data script that tries to run an `aws` command:

```
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 7: aws: command not found
```

Then I connected with SSH to the instance for a sanity check, and `aws` is definitely not found:

```
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X ~]$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X ~]$ aws --version
-bash: aws: command not found
```

I thought the AWS CLI was installed by default on all AmazonLinux AMIs? I don't remember ever having to install it myself before.

This article even says that the CLI v1 is installed by default on AmazonLinux2:

[AWS Docs Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux-al2017.html)

So how is it possible that it's not found on this stock AMI? Do only some of the AmazonLinux2 AMIs have the CLI pre-installed? For reference, I am using this AMI:

`amzn2-ami-minimal-hvm-2.0.20200917.0-x86_64-ebs (ami-0a6993b2978bd23cb)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=273480) on AWS forum:

> Minimal has a smaller set of packages installed by default. For example, a lot of **AWS specific packages** are installed on the default for easy integration to other AWS services. **The minimal do not have these installed.** This gives a much lower footprint for those who are not directly interacting with other AWS services, or who want to cherry-pick which ones they install.

If you want `awscli`, you can install it:

```
sudo yum install -y awscli
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish the official docs said that. I switched back from the minimal to the regular image and it has the CLI as expected.

Answer (score 1):

to install the latest version of the awscli (v2) see [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html)

```sh
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```